# MYSQL - How to build this query?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, aggregate-functions

I would like to get a list of groups and their members shown (only once) given only a member name:

**Table_a:**

```
| GROUP_ID |   NAME |
---------------------
|        1 |    Tom |
|        2 |  Frank |
|        3 | Shilla |
|        1 | Scully |
|        3 | Scully |
|        3 | Scully |
|        3 | Scully |
|        4 | Scully |
|        1 |    Jen |
```

**Table_b:**

```
| ID | GROUP_NAME |
-------------------
|  1 |   Troopers |
|  2 |      Clubs |
|  3 |  Mavericks |
|  4 |   Tomatoes |
```

Here's the [SQLFidlle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b6e70/3)
This is the result:

```
| GROUP_NAME |        GROUP_CONCAT(C.NAME) |
--------------------------------------------
|  Mavericks | Scully,Scully,Scully,Shilla |
|   Tomatoes |                      Scully |
|   Troopers |              Scully,Jen,Tom |
```

What I would like to get is

```
| GROUP_NAME | GROUP_CONCAT(C.NAME) |
-------------------------------------
|  Mavericks | Scully,Shilla        |
|   Tomatoes | Scully               |
|   Troopers | Scully,Jen,Tom       |
```

How should I change the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just add `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT  b.GROUP_NAME, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.Name)
FROM    
        (
            SELECT GROUP_ID
            FROM   table_a
            WHERE  name = 'Scully'
            GROUP BY table_a.GROUP_ID
        ) a 
        INNER JOIN table_b b
            ON a.GROUP_ID = b.ID
        INNER JOIN table_a c
            ON a.GROUP_ID = c.GROUP_ID
GROUP BY b.GROUP_NAME;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b6e70/5)

Answer (score 2):

Just add DISTINCT to your GROUP_CONCAT. See the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
... GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT C.NAME) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM table_b as b
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
          GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT NAME) as Names,
          GROUP_ID
    FROM Table_a 
    GROUP BY GROUP_ID
) as a ON a.GROUP_ID = b.ID
```

[SQL FIddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b6e70/13)

Comment: I need this result : Shilla,Scully,Scully,Scully to be: to be Shilla,Scully